# How to check Google web application in iPhone

Tags: java, iphone, gwt, smartgwt

I have designed a google web application using Eclipse and the Google GWT plugin.

Is there some way I can see the GUI of my application on iPhone or iPad.
Please, give me suggestions or tell me if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a company server (IP 10.24.56.34). If that is a web server that you or someone from your company can administer, then follow the below process:

- In eclipse select your project, right click on it, go to google
  option and select GWT compile.
- At the pop-up press compile.
- Wait some time (can be a lot, if your project is big/complex).
- After compilation has finished successfully, go to your workspace
  using an filesystem explorer utility (Note: Right click your project in
  Eclipse, select project properties, select resource to find your
  project's location on disk, if you have any doubt as to where it is
  located.
- Inside project's directory, you should find a war directory. Copy all its contents
  in a suitable directory for your webserver to be able to publish.
- Hit the werbserver's IP and the publish location you used at the previous step, appending the name of the only HTML file you will find in the above mentioned war directory. You should be able to see your application. Of course you can browse this location from a browser from your PC to make sure you do not have iPhone related issues.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac you can install Xcode and then see it in the simulator by typing in the localhost URL. That should give a pretty good indication of how it will look.

You may also be able to make your computer visible on the local wi-fi network by enabling web sharing and then just access it by IP address from the iPhone browser.

Alternatively, if you set up your computer as an adhoc wireless network, you can connect to it from your iPhone (select your computer as the wi-fi router) and again access it from the iPhone browser using its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode you'll have to use -bindAddress and use an address that you can access from your phone. If you have a local wireless that both your compter and iphone can connect to then using -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 will bind to your wireless card IP address (so you don't have to type it). On my laptop it looks like this:

```
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
http://192.168.1.100:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.100:9997
```

then just open this address in iPhone.

Comment: :I am not very good in these things. i will tell you discription. My laptop is connected to company server with ip (eg 10.24.56.34)
where is -bindAddress. ??
can you tell me step by step.

Comment: -bindAddress is a GWT dev mode parameter. how do you start dev mode anyway? in eclipse?